# Proof problem about inequality

Tags: proof-explanation

*Question:* **Given x > sinx for x > 0, prove
πx - 2x^2 > sin2x for 0 < x < π/2**

This is a problem about inequality that involves trig, I tried to divide the RHSs and LHSs by x > sinx to get π /2 - x > cosx, and stuck on it.

I am not sure the way I am trying to work out is correct or not. If correct, then how to eliminate the cosx? Is it related to the π/2?

Answer (score 1):

Work from the answer,

πx-2x^2 > sin 2x

π/2*x-x^2 > sinxcosx

π/2 - x > cosx

π/2 > cox+sinx

Since 1<cosx+sinx< squared root of 2, (as above)
then work back to reach the statement.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).